# How do I activate SSL on a custom domain in Google AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I am able to serve my AppEngine site thru a custom (http) domain, but can not see the "SSL" subtab in the "Domain Settings".

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you read this document? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Comment: Yes, it is the basis for everything I am trying here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL for Custom Domains isn't launched yet.  However as the observant may have noticed (docs, admin console, 1.7.0 release notes), the launch is imminent.  Stay tuned for the [blog](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/) post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the reason might be - you must have an App Engine application with billing enabled that has cleared at least one billing charge.

Comment: The app has billing enabled and cleared many billing charges, so this can't be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your app to use a custom domain?  The subtab won't appear until you do.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain